# RDFS, Jena: how to query taking ontology into account

Tags: rdf, jena, ontology, rdfs

I have two separate Jena models, one containing an RDFS ontology and the other containing the statements.

Right now I cannot, for example, write a query which returns all results for a particular class, since the class is not described in the RDF statements.

What I want is to query the statements model by taking into account the ontology as well. How can I do this?

Comment: You'd generally either create a new union model of the two, or create a new model and add all the triples from the other two into the new one.  Have you a preferences between those two options?  Also, with an inference model, you have the option of specifying a base model and a schema model, so you might do that, using your statements model as the base, and the RDFS ontology as the schema model.

Comment: I outlined a few options.  Which worked for you? I'll be happy to post it as an answer, or try to find an appropriate duplicate…

Comment: I created a union of the two models by having creating a submodel for the ontology. In code: `ontologyModel.addSubModel(statementsModel)`. After this, I apply the query to the `onologyModel`. There is also a `Model union` function in Jena, but this does the trick. Post it as an answer as well if you wish so.

Answer (score -2):

You can query the ontology using SPARQL language and store the result and you can query other statements using any normal querying language.

After that you can combine the results obtained from the above two