# How to get constructed result to take ontology into account

Tags: sparql, rdf, owl, dbpedia, graphdb

I am playing around (for now, but with purpose) with GraphDB and SPARQL. What I am trying to achieve now is to query from external source (DBPedia in this case), and use locally loaded ontology to analyze the result. For this, I have imported into my GraphDB repository the DBPedia ontology into a named graph [schema only](http://downloads.dbpedia.org/2014/dbpedia_2014.owl.bz2) (no *data* statements).

Now, I am issuing following query:

```
PREFIX dbp: <http://dbpedia.org/property/>
PREFIX dbo: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>

construct {
    ?city dbo:country ?country .
    ?city dbo:population ?apop .
}
WHERE {    
    SERVICE <https://dbpedia.org/sparql> 
    {
        {
            ?city   dbo:populationTotal | dbo:totalPopulation | dbo:population ?apop ;
                                                               a dbo:City ;
                                                               dbo:country ?country
            .
            FILTER(?apop > 1000000)
        }
    }
}
```

`dbo:population` is a defined as property in the ontology:

```
<owl:ObjectProperty rdf:about="http://dbpedia.org/ontology/population">
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#Property"/>
    <rdfs:label xml:lang="en">population</rdfs:label>
    <rdfs:domain rdf:resource="http://dbpedia.org/ontology/PopulatedPlace"/>
    <rdfs:range rdf:resource="http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Population"/>
    <prov:wasDerivedFrom rdf:resource="http://mappings.dbpedia.org/index.php/OntologyProperty:population"/>
</owl:ObjectProperty>
```

The table view contains these properties. Still, when I am trying to visualize the result, it tells me that the cities do not have any property:

[image]

I even tried to add `dbo:population a rdf:Property`, which made this statement appear in the graph, but nothing more. Following the advice from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23856837/rdfs-jena-how-to-query-taking-ontology-into-account), I have constructed an union of the `dbo` graph and my result:

```
PREFIX dbp: <http://dbpedia.org/property/>
PREFIX dbo: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>

construct {
    ?city dbo:country ?country .
    ?city dbo:population ?apop .
    ?o ?p ?s.
}
FROM <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/owl>
WHERE {
    {
        ?o ?p ?s
    }
    UNION {
        SERVICE <https://dbpedia.org/sparql> 
        {
            {
                ?city   dbo:populationTotal | dbo:totalPopulation | dbo:population ?apop ;
                                                               a dbo:City ;
                                                               dbo:country ?country
                FILTER(?apop > 1000000)            
            }
        }   
    }
}
```

Which resulted in a large graph I was unable to visualize, but the table view showed everything from DBPedia ontology and the remote result.

*Virtuoso* handles schema separately, and they can be imported, but has no built-in visualizer. I was unable to find a way to tell GraphDB's visualizer to use specific schema for a graph. The repository has default ruleset *RDFS-Plus (optimized)*, and the manually added property declaration from before was properly inferred as being `owl:ObjectProperty`.

I am little bit confused. How can I "combine" a federated result set with a local ontology properly?

Comment: did you try `{
       VALUES ?p {dbo:populationTotal  dbo:totalPopulation  dbo:population dbo:country} ?p ?o ?s . 
    }
    UNION {` - you should also try `construct {
    ?city dbo:country ?country .
    ?city dbo:populationTotal ?apop .` because `dbo:population` is a object property in DBpedia

Comment: @AKSW `dbo:populationTotal` was my first guess, but gives the same result. The query with `VALUES` added extra statements from the ontology to the graph, but no properties to the cities.

Comment: Hm I cannot reproduce this. I tried your first query at http://factforge.net/sparql - it works and fetches properties even not contained in the query via Linked Data principle. Can you try it on the Factforge SPARQL endpoint. This is what you expect, right?

Comment: @AKSW Yes, sort of. But this tool has all the data preloaded from DBPedia. My GraphDB instance shows properties if querying from local data.

Comment: I see. I tried it locally, found out that the `SERVICE` request is the problem. All those stuff like the node color, label, retrieval, property retrieval is based in queries that you can configure in the "Visual Graph" view, where you can setup a custom config. BUT: all those queries do **not** work on the result of the `CONSTRUCT` query. Which means, for example in the "Node extra" tab you have to configure the query such that it does the lookup via the `SERVICE` keyword.